# Opening folder within a url

Tags: apache2

I am new to Ubuntu server, so learning as I go along. I have followed a tutorial for setting up Ubuntu server and everything for getting my server running with `apache2` and `ISPConfig`.

My main site runs fine, but I use a folder for when I am messing around with web pages scripts. I used to host on Windows and I didn't have to change anything : it displayed the content of the folder when typed in the URL-bar, but this is not working on this setup.

I have another folder with an index file in it, and this runs ok, so I put an index file in the folder I am having trouble with, and it opened that without any trouble.

My guess is that there is probably something simple to change in `apache` settings so it can read a directory and not looking for an index file... but I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone help please ?

I hope that all this makes sense.

Comment: The reason Windows allowed to access the folder might be because Windows is insecure :D - most people don't want other people rifling around their websites folders...

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

Add directory option to Apache configuration file `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And add Following code:

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/pdfs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Save and close the file.

Then restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

OR

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

---

**Option 2:**

You can place config line `Options Indexes` in `.htaccess` file. Make sure `.htaccess` file support is enabled.

```
sudo nano .htaccess
```

Append following apache directive:

```
Options Indexes
```

Save and close the file.

---

*Taken from [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/) Page (written in 2007)*

Comment: That seems right, but for Ubuntu, you should replace the `vi` command with `sudo nano`, which is more easy to use for simple tasks like these. And @MarioSegura, please don't direclty link another web-page, if it's down, the person will not have the answer. Please quote this link and write the answer directly.

Comment: Alright thanks, sorry I'm new to askubuntu. I shall make changes to it right now

Comment: I edited your post, you could do something like that.

Comment: @MrVaykadji - You can use `vi` - but `nano` works much better :-)

Comment: Let's just say that I tried `vi` ONCE... and I wasn't able to even close it without searching the web >< (fyi : you have to type `:q` to close vi)

Comment: @MarioSegura : did you forgot to add "Change directory to pdfs: `cd pdfs`" in Option2 ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji Well people have different directories. Thought it would be common sense, should I put it in?

Comment: I don't know, never used Apache :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply couldn't figure out your method 1, couldn't get it to work but I used part of method 2, I used the .htaccess file from the web folder and added Options Indexes to it but that didn't work but I added **Options +Indexes** to it (taken from comments from the page your answer was from) and now it work thanks very much for help :)